# Creating a multidimensional array of maps in es6

Tags: javascript, nested, immutable.js

i have an array of immutable lists array = [List, List]
Each list contains Maps. I want to create an array which contains the Maps of each list. My code is the following:

```
const content = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < types.length; i += 1) {
      let j = 0;
      while (j < types[i].length) {
        content[i] = types[i].get(j);
        j += 1;
      }
    }
```

But when i `console.log` this it shows me an empty array. The desired output should be something like this content[0] = [Map, Map, Map, Map] content[1] = [Map, Map, Map, Map]

Comment: Did you add a `console.log()` or breakpoint to make sure both of your loops are actually running? Please also show what `types` contains.

Comment: I use a console log yes and the loops are running. The types array is types= [List, List]

Comment: @user7334203 the `toArray()` method might be useful in converting a `List` into an array? https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/toArray. That way, you won't be needing your while loop.

Comment: `content[i].push(types[i].get(j))`

Comment: My mistake, this approach didnt work. Maybe my initial approach is false....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript in the question is overwriting `content[i]` in the `while` loop; `content[i]` is not an array. Define `content[i]` as an array before the `while` loop, and use `.push()` within the `while` loop.

```
const content = [];

for (let i = 0; i < types.length; i += 1) {
  let j = 0;
  content[i] = [];
  while (j < types[i].length) {
    content[i].push(types[i].get(j));
    j += 1;
  }
}
```